# java.lang.RuntimeException: Stream '/jars/oozie-examples.jar' was not found. while running spark workflow from oozie in CDH 5.8

Tags: apache-spark, oozie, cloudera-cdh, hue

well i am trying to run the sample spark workflow example from hue-oozie. I am facing below error

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Stream '/jars/oozie-examples.jar' was not found.`

[image]

Below is the configuration from workflow logs

[image]

Below is spark setting
[image]

Generated workflow.xml from logs

[image]

Comment: I tried to provide explicit file path for jar instead of browsing to the jar file as below   `/user/hue/oozie/workspaces/workflows/spark-scala/lib/oozie-examples.jar` but still the jar is not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide full HDFS path for input file with `hdfs://` prefix, so in your case `hdfs:///user/hue/oozie/workspaces/workflows/spark-scala/lib/oozie-e‌​xamples.jar` should work.